# Right way to embed HTML Pages to angular app

Tags: html, angular, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building my own website with Angular2 coupled with Spring boot and postgres as Backend.

The login/logout features are built to perfection but I have trouble understanding how to develop a site like geeksforgeeks where there are multiple links in a page and each page hosts different kind of content.

The idea is large scale and I intend to have lot of pages(topics) as I develop further.

My question is :

1)Should I be creating as many HTML Pages

2)Or What is the standard way of doing it.

I just want to know the right direction, have been scratching my head for quite some time with unsatisfactory solutions.

Comment: You should create components instead of pages. Also Angular2 is all about re-usability. So if anything that you are using for multiple times then you can create one component out of it and use the same for multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should not create as many HTML pages.

1. Plan to make a category of your type or section of posts
2. Define templates for each category (e.g. Review something, generic blog post, some solution, etc)
3. Get the post json from backend along with section or type
4. Bind it to preferred template to your view

Comment: Thanks Zico, I had the backend defined in the way you described without the categorisation, was just contemplating if its the right approach . Seems like it is. Thanks a lot for the right direction.